# Nginx upstream connection prematurely closed by upstream

Tags: node.js, nginx

I have node server running behind Nginx.

Time to time I get this error -

**upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream,**

My upstream settings -

```
upstream prodpass {
    server 127.0.0.1:3001;
    keepalive 64;
  }
```

We have more than 5000 connections at the same time open. What should be the value of keepalive?

Comment: The answer very much depends on your case. One thing I did before is to test several keepalive connections (in your case, increasing the number). You can also tune keepalive_timeout or keepalive_request to avoid connection being closed.

Comment: Can you give me a sample config keeping 5000 connection open at one time?

Comment: you mean a use case or the code?

Comment: Code sample. In upsteam I am setting keepalive to 2000. Still when there is load on system, files do not get servied.

Comment: In this case, you should consider load balancing.

Comment: Hi, i had this error for a long while, i just fixed the problem in my node API. Before i give you an answer, I have to ask: Do you use a systemd service to launch your node app ?